# SEO on an existing platform

Tags: seo, google, optimization, conversions

I'm given the task to increase user visits and conversions on for a recruitment website.
Conversions would be interested job seekers submitting their CV.

The manager would first like to increase the organic search results and optimize the website before starting with targeted campaigns.

The problem is, they are using a proprietary recruitment software platform which I can barely add changes to. For example, the url's all look like dynamic url's without any semantic meaning and the markup is almost completely build automatically by that platform.

I'm also confident that the lack of submitted CV's is due to a bad user experience of the website (no incentives or clear CTA to register)

Besides optimizing the static texts and page titles, is there anything I can do?

Comment: What specifically CAN you change?  Page layout, image alt descriptions, breadcrumb trails, etc?  You say that the software almost completely builds meaningless urls....do you know the language the software is written in?

Answer (score 2):

In short - no. With regards to on-page SEO, the markup of the site and the url structure are fundamentally important to increasing organic traffic.

Unless you can find a way to optimise the pages, i fear your efforts may be in vain.